# How can I replace socat code with python code

Tags: python, linux, serial-port, socat

Right now I'm using subprocess to create communication between two virtual serial ports as such:

```
  def socat_runner(self):
      self.socat_subprocess = subprocess.Popen(['socat', '-d', '-d', 'pty,raw,echo=0', 'pty,raw,echo=0'],
                                                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
      print("subproc id: ", self.socat_subprocess.pid)
      line = self.socat_subprocess.stdout.readline().decode().strip('\n')
      port_location_in_string = line.find('/dev/pts')
      self.port1 = line[port_location_in_string:]
      line = self.socat_subprocess.stdout.readline().decode()
      port_location_in_string = line.find('/dev/pts')
      self.port2 = line[port_location_in_string:]
```

I'm using both port1 and port2

I would to replace this CMD approach with python approach

Comment: Use the `socket` module. A more detailed answer would require writing dozens of lines of code for you. Read a tutorial.